# General procedure for reading serial data bytes of unknown and variable length

Tags: python, pyserial

The following is part of a procedure I have written which sends a command to an ECU and expects to read back 107 raw bytes which are not terminated with \n or similar.

```
def send_packet(data):

    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, 10400, timeout=0.1)   
    ser.write(data)
    
    time.sleep(0.11) #wait 110ms until all data is received
 
    read_val = ser.read(107)   
    return read_val
```

read_val correctly gets me all the bytes so long as I wait at least 110ms before reading the buffer.

However other commands may return widely varying number of bytes for which the above method is inelegant, may not work or rather wasteful.

How can I write a general purpose procedure which is capable of handling varying lengths with no terminating string but with a reasonable gap until the next read?

Comment: the best would be first send information how many bytes will be send - and then receiver will know how many bytes it has to get - and then it may run `read()` in loop until it gets all data.

Comment: The problem is that my program, the receiver, does not know many bytes the ECU will send since information on the ECU is sketchy.